# Pos_hint with Kivy ScrollView

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm having trouble achieving the layout I want using scrollview. My current approach is a series of labels stacked vertically in a StackLayout to form each column. Then each column is stacked horizontally in a StackLayout which is the child widget of the ScrollView. When there are enough StackLayout columns to fill the width of the screen everything works well. But when there are too few columns, the columns that exist are left justified. Using pos_hint to bring them to the right doesn't seem to work.

I know I could create empty layouts of the appropriate width to fill the gap, but is there any way to get my parent StackLayout to right align within the scrollview? The relevant KV code is below:

```
MDScreen:

    MDBoxLayout:

        id: box
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        
        ScrollView:
            id: scroll
            size_hint_x: .75
            do_scroll_x: True
            scroll_x:1

            StackLayout:
                orientation: 'tb-rl'
                size_hint: None ,1
                width: self.minimum_width
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
    
                StackLayout:
                    orientation: 'tb-rl'
                    size_hint: None, 1
                    width: scroll.width *.3
                    
                    MDLabel:
                        text: 'Date'
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: 99
                                    
                    MDLabel:
                        text: 'hi'
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: 125
                    
                    MDLabel:
                        text: 'hi'
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: 125

                    MDLabel:
                        text: 'hi'
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: 125

                StackLayout:
                    orientation: 'tb-rl'
                    size_hint: None, 1
                    width: scroll.width *.3
                

                    MDLabel:
                        text: 'Date'
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: 99
                                    
                    MDLabel:
                        text: 'hi'
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: 125
                    
                    MDLabel:
                        text: 'hi'
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: 125

                    MDLabel:
                        text: 'hi'
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: 125
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Comment: Try using `halign: 'center'` in the `MDLabels`.

Comment: John, halign: 'center' works just fine but is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for the columns to stack from right to left. As is, the first column is positioned on the far left, then the second is added on the far left bumping the first over one spot and so on. I want the first to show up on the right then each subsequent one to show up left of the existing columns.